# Xor of binary strings in java

Tags: java

i am using the following code to XOR 2 strings

```
String lseq = "0011111111101111111111111100101101111100110000001011111000010100";
String tseq = "0011111111100000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < lseq.length(); i++)
    sb.append((lseq.charAt(i) ^ tseq.charAt(i)));

String result = sb.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

The above code gives me correct output :

```
0000000000001111001100110000011110110000000011000111001011011000
```

I need to XOR one more string

```
String hseq = "0011111111110010010111110100010111100000101101001110000100011110";
```

if i try `sb.append((lseq.charAt(i) ^ tseq.charAt(i) ^ hseq.charAt(i));`

I am getting result :

```
48484848484848484848484948484948494848494848494949484848494848494848494849494848484949494948484848484948494948494949484948484948
```

which is wrong. I need help in doing xor of 3 binary strings

Comment: You are confusing bits with characters. The character "0" has nothing to do with the bit '0'

Comment: @leonbloy well, it does end with `0` . `0011 000` `0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do it like this

```
private static boolean bitOf(char in) {
    return (in == '1');
}

private static char charOf(boolean in) {
    return (in) ? '1' : '0';
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String lseq ="0011111111101111111111111100101101111100110000001011111000010100";
    String tseq ="0011111111100000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100";
    String hseq ="0011111111110010010111110100010111100000101101001110000100011110";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < lseq.length(); i++) {
        sb.append(charOf(bitOf(lseq.charAt(i)) ^ bitOf(tseq.charAt(i))
                ^ bitOf(hseq.charAt(i))));
    }

    String result = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Which outputs

```
0011111111111101011011000100001001010000101110001001001111000110
```

Comment: Why not use Character.digit(ch,2) and Character.forDigit(int,2) to convert in each direction between character and bit?

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider something like this:

```
String lseq = "0011111111101111111111111100101101111100110000001011111000010100";
String tseq = "0011111111100000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100";
String hseq = "0011111111110010010111110100010111100000101101001110000100011110";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < lseq.length(); i++)
    sb.append((lseq.charAt(i) - '0' ^ tseq.charAt(i) - '0' ^ hseq.charAt(i) - '0'));

String result = sb.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

Under the hood, a `char` is treated like an `int` in that the numeric value represents a pre-defined character. We can subtract the value of the character '0' from our character (knowing that the value of '1' is only 1 more than '0') and get either 0 or 1, which can be used with the `^` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), it will make your code simpler. It has a constructor where you can pass a String and the base you want to use (2 in your case).

Then you can do a XOR calling `public BigInteger xor(BigInteger val)` (see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#xor%28java.math.BigInteger%29) or take a look to [openjdk BigInteger's code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigInteger.java#BigInteger.xor%28java.math.BigInteger%29))