# bitCount results in error, possible fix?

Tags: java, binary

Trying to find the no of `1's`(set bits) in a binary number. And I am able to get the result for smaller numbers, but when the number gets big, it crashes, here is the code:

```
    public class time {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String a = "1001101111101011011100101100100110111011111011000100111100111110111101011011011100111001100011111010";
        int x = Integer.bitCount(Integer.parseInt(a, 2)); 
        System.out.println(x);

    }


}
```

Where `a` is a string representation of a binary number of 100 digits, now when I try to get the `bitCount()`, the compiler says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   String
>   "1001101111101011011100101100100110111011111011000100111100111110111101011011011100111001100011111010"

So my **question is:** what's the possible fix for large numbers like this?

NB: I also need to perform the same operation on 500 digit numbers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "1001101111101011011100101100100110111011111011000100111100111110111101011011011100111001100011111010";
    int x = new BigInteger(a, 2).bitCount(); 
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

This creates a `Biginteger` from the input String in base 2 ([`new BigInteger(val, radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-java.lang.String-int-)) and returns its bit count ([`bitCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#bitCount--)).

This method will work for Strings of any length (up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) so it will also work for small Strings, although it won't be as performant as using the primitive solution.

---

As pointed out [Sleiman Jneidi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/822588/sleiman-jneidi) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35612029/1743880), if you're really only interested in the bit count then since you already have the binary representation as a `String` then you actually don't need to convert it into a number, you can just count the number of 1's in the `String`. A sample implementation using Java 8 would be:

```
long x = a.chars().filter(c -> c == '1').count();
```

Comment: Thanks, so is this the best way to do this? As another answer points me to count manually by iterating? What do you think?

Comment: If you're only interested in the bit count and nothing else, the other answer will be a lot simpler yes.

Comment: I need to perform an `OR` operation with these, say two 100 digit numbers, only then I need the count(), and with the above code with BigInteger, I get trouble, any help on that will be much appreciated, thanks again for the splendid answer!

Comment: @shaheen You can call `BigInteger.or` to make that operation. Or you could also do everything still without parsing numbers, like [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20745456/1743880).

Comment: Thanks @Tunaki, solved the problem. This was what I was trying to solve:https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/acm-icpc-team

Answer (score 2):

The bit string you have doesn't fit into a 32 bit integer, and hence you getting the error.

You don't need to convert to integer to get the bit count, you can just iterate and count the number of 1's in the string.

Comment: Thanks, but again I need to perform `OR` operation on another number of this length? Best possible solution in that case?

Comment: @shaheen you can do it directly on the bit string

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you are trying to store a value that falls outside of the range of an int. Very far outside of the range in fact, BigInteger is the only way to fix this, because even "long" can't hold such a large value. This is a common problem, make sure to be careful when dealing with storing large values in java (or the possiblity). Here is a quick review:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_datatypes.htm